# Как открыть консоль процесса linux

Tags: linux

Запускаю программу на сервере, которая постоянно отчитывается в консоль :D Так вот, к серверу я подключаюсь по ssh, и у меня такое бывает что почему-то ssh закрывается самостоятельно (мб из-за того что я афк смотрю в консоль) и при повторном подключении процесс висит, а консоль уже новая (не этого процесса). Подскажите как мне открыть поток в который пишет моя программа?
Пробовал пользоваться утилитой strace, через htop посмотрел pid процесса (у меня их почему-то несколько, но пробовал все) и писал strace -p{pid} -e write, но все тщетно...

Comment: а как именно Вы запускаете свою программу? может можно запустить с перенаправлением в файл? `./yourprogramm > log.txt` и потом всегда можно через `tail -f log.txt` и подсматривать

Comment: @KoVadim здравстуйте, я запускаю jar'ник) просто java -jar ... Вообще, я рассматривал вариант писать лог, но это крайне неудобно: во-первых, мне бы очень хотелось в realtime смотреть за работой, а не каждый раз чекать лог (+ я не уверен что если одновременно писать в файл и читать его, все будет ок), а во-вторых, вес такого лога будет расти до колоссальных объемов, что тоже не очень удобно. Я подсмотрел способ с утилитой strace, но почему-то у меня это не работает(((

Comment: strace - это не для логов. tail -f как раз позволяет подсматривать логи в реальном времени. И если Вы не сделаете ничего хитрого, то и никаких проблем не будет. Если у Вас система с поддержкой systemd (а это почти все современные дистрибутивы), то просто напишите правильный unit файл и все Ваши логи сразу попадут в ротацию, само приложение будет корректно перезапускаться и все другие плюшки. Если же лень все это делать, просто запускайте это все в screen/tmux и радуйтесь

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо Вам, пойду покурю мануал по tail :D

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4035/110559

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно что-то типа мультиплексора терминалов - `screen`, `tmux` или новомодный `mosh`.

Запускаете screen командой `screen`

Если переподключились, в свою сессию можно попасть командой `screen -x`

Также в нем можно наоткрывать много консолей - `CTRL-A-C` открывает консоль. Это аккорд, сначала нажимаете `CTRL-A`, отпускаете, потом нажимаете C.

Аналогично, можно переключаться между  консолями командой `CTRL-A-цифра`

или `CTRL-A-P` (предидущая) и `CTRL-A-N` - следующая

Comment: Я понял Вас, слышал про screen и tmux, даже немножечко пользовался)) Но проблема немного в другом (я понял как решить этот вопрос, скажем tmux, спасибо :D): вот сейчас например у меня уже запущен процесс и я, к примеру, закрываю терминал с моим ssh; потом заново захожу по ssh и вижу через htop что процесс до сих пор работает, как мне посмотреть что он там пишет, если я предварительно не пользовался tmux etc...?